# Complex Linq query errors "..Entities does not recognize the method.."

Tags: wcf, linq, entity

I'm starting to write a wcf web service using the .NET 4.5 Entity Framework.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to output the following linq query
here's my code:

```
using (var context = new myEntities())
{

var countResultsByArea = from v in context.vPerson
                        join pe in context.pEvent on v.pevent_id equals pe.pevent_id
                        join pd in context.pEventArea on pe.pevent_id equals pd.pevent_id
                        join d in context.dArea on pd.darea_id equals d.darea_id
                        join z in
                            (
                                from el in context.event
                                select new { el.event_id, el.title_1, el.title_2, el.event_date }
                            ) on pe.event_id equals z.event_id
                        where (v.status.ToString() == "A" || v.status.ToString() == "P") && pe.event_id == 800
                                        && new[] { 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449 }.Contains(pd.area_id)
                        group new { d, z, v } by new { d.name_1, z.title_1 } into y
                        let myGroup = y.FirstOrDefault()
                        let myDArea = myGroup.d
                        let myPEvent = myGroup.z
                        select new { distArea = myDArea.name_1, title = y.Max(x => x.z.title_1), personCount = y.Count() };

if (countResultsByArea != null)
    foreach (var item in countResultsByArea)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.distArea);
        Console.WriteLine(item.title);
        Console.WriteLine(item.personCount);
    }
else
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error retrieving voter count by CD", "Error"));

}
```

I'm not getting errors until the foreach loop which returns an error of:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

I've seen other questions here with answers that uses .AsEnumerable to output the query as a List but I'm not sure how to modify the linq query since its so complex.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, a LINQ query can never equal `null`.

Comment: vt.status is likely already a string - remove the `ToString` call. (Remove the `ToString` in any case.)

Comment: @user2246674 ... wow that did the trick!  i tested the linq query in LinqPad and it kept wanting me to use .ToString in that where statement ... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, EF's query translator doesn't know what to do with `ToString()`.

If that is a `char`, you can compare it to a character literal directly using single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the .ToString() on the v.status field.

```
where (v.status == "A" || v.status == "P") && pe.event_id == 800
```